# Webservice reference cannot find assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, reference, tfs

I have a c# project with a reference that cannot be found when checking in to TFS. The project runs fine when i debug. 
It its in my services project the problem is located. I have a reference to  lets say ProjectSec. And i have a wewbservice reference to Projectservice. 
The webservice uses the ProjectSecurity.Security namespace that is located in the ProcectSec assembly.

When i check in my files i get the following error:

- The type or namespace name 'ProjectSecurity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ProjectSec". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

The ProjectSec.dll is located in the lib folder and its there. There is  no error when i try to use it elsewhere in my project.

This may not be a perfect explanation but does anyone know what i could try?

I have removed the reference and added it over again, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common pitfall with TFS-build is to have in Source Control something, for example, like this:

```
$/Sources/Webservice
$/Libs/ProjectSecurity
```

And then, in the build definition that is validating your checkin, to have only

```
Active | $/Sources/Webservice | $(SourceDir)
```

as workspace mappings.
(You can access this by right-clicking on the build definition in TeamExplorer, select "Edit Build Definition.." & go to Tab "Workspace")

Comment: Fixed it my self. Reading panteleif's answer made me take a closer look at the Source Control. I tried to add the .dll manually to the Source Control built and viola, it built successfully.